# Maintaining the datetime format from SQL Server to C# and back to SQL Server

Tags: c#, datetime

I get the `lastupdated` date from SQL Server 2008 which has the follow value "2010-12-01 22:14:49.253'.

Then I display this in a gridview and when the user checks this row to delete .

I need to check this value against the `lastupdated` date in SQL Server before saving.

The problem is when I convert this to `datetime` it removes the hrs,mins and sec.

So when I compare it fails.

Can some body tell me how I can maintian the date format?

SQL Server 2008  - datatype is `datetime`

C#.net uses

```
DateTime dt = DateTime(dr["LastUpdateDateTime"]);   
object.lastdatetime  = dt;
```

binds the object to a datagrid

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="LastUpdateDateTime"  ItemStyle-CssClass="hidcolumn">
```

retrieves the data from grid using gridview1.Rows

```
{ 
   gc.LastUpdateDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[9].Text);
}
```

and passes it to the datalayer

```
 new SqlParameter("@lastUpdateDate", lastUpdateDate);
```

calls the Stored procedure

I think when binding to the Gridview is when the time information is getting lost.

Comment: How are you converting the datetime? Where does it lose precision? Can you post the code?

Comment: object.LastUpdateDateTime = (DateTime)(dr["lastupdatedatetime"]);

Comment: Is that where the precision is lost? Does `LastUpdateDateTime` not contain the time?

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question**: when debugging, what is the value / datatype of your `dt` here?? Does this still contain the full date including the time??

```
DateTime dt = DateTime(dr["LastUpdateDateTime"]);   
object.lastdatetime  = dt;
```

**Second question**: do you specify a `DataFormatString` in your `<asp:BoundField>` ?? Check out the [MSDN Docs on DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) to see what you can set in there - maybe you're truncating off the time portion here (by not specifying anything).....

**Third question**: when you debug through, what do you see in `row.Cells[9].Text` here, and what is the value of `gc.LastUpdateDateTime` after this convert?? Does this still contain hours, minutes, seconds??

```
{ 
   gc.LastUpdateDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[9].Text);
}
```

**Fourth question/recommendation**: when using `SqlParameter`, I **always** specify the data type. .NET is pretty good at guessing - but it's just that - guessing - why not **tell it** what the data is??

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@lastUpdateDate", SqlDbType.DataTime);
param.Value = lastUpdateDate;
```